# Lines between columns in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

We are currently upgrading our system and moving our databases to new servers and a new MySQL version (4.8.5), and we will also be using a new phpMyAdmin. One of the differences I've noticed in appearence is that there are no longer any lines between columns. Is this something that can be set on a user level so that I can add them back in (to make columns in big tables more easily readable) with an option, or would I need to have access to a CSS-file or something else to change these?

[image: Lines]

[image: No Lines]

Comment: Please open an issue on our Github tracker we will fix it https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to open an issue once I remember my github login. Been too long since I was on there posting. :)